# Sass and Compass for PHP

Tags: php, css, sass, css-frameworks, compass-sass

Is there any CSS frameworks like [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) and [Compass](http://compass-style.org/) for developing in PHP that use similar methods of CSS abstraction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two PHP based CSS proccesors that I found:

- http://github.com/anthonyshort/Scaffold/wiki
- http://pcss.wiq.com.br/

Answer (score 6):

Yeah - how about Sass and Compass? I'm using these with PHP right now. Although they rely on Ruby for compiling this doesn't mean that you can't use these solution to deploy css on your PHP sites.

The framework Symfony has an asset manager called Assetic that includes a Compass filter allowing direct compilation of Sass into CSS as part of your development process (in PHP).

https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic

Comment: Okay I didn't know that. My Ruby skills aren't so proficient so I'm going to see if there are any others perhaps specifically made for PHP.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is you don't have to know ruby AT ALL. As long as you can install packages in linux then you're all set. Example 'sudo apt-get install ruby rubygems' then 'sudo gem install compass'. Bang - you're done.

Comment: Let me put it another way. How much do I know about cars? Not a whole lot - but I drive one every day.

Comment: Okay, I get what you saying. Can you do this in Windows? Also if I'm going to be using shared hosting how would I install it?

Comment: I did find one https://github.com/anthonyshort/Scaffold/wiki it seems that I could just place it somewhere on the server and root all css requests through the parser.

Comment: Just adding to your example I don't think I even know how to drive the car in this case :)

Comment: Well most hosts these days have ruby installed but that isn't a big deal because you can compile your sass locally and then only deploy the CSS (which would be the sensible thing to do anyway - you want to pre compile your assets). I use windows too but I run Linux in a VM - this is a really good solution for development (and it's free). You can also install ruby for Windows natively but I would highly reccommend Linux in a VM (Ubuntu in Virtualbox).

Comment: Okay will experiment, thanks for your help!

Comment: This may have been an appropriate answer for @ChaimChaikin but it's not correct.  I'm looking for Sass/LESS/Compass-like functionality written in PHP because the variables can be changed by the user and compiling a new file from the preprocessor for each change is VERY slow.

Comment: @brian No - it _is_ correct. The question was "for developing in PHP" - not "Written in PHP". Regardless - you seem to be complaining about the fact that the preprocessing would require new complication on changes. This would be exactly the same if written in PHP. Can you explain your comment and downvote please? Edit: And define 'VERY' slow. It takes less than a second on my machine. By the time I switch to the browser the changes are ready to load.

Comment: It's pretty straightforward - I'm working with WordPress Theme Customizer on my 16gb RAM local instance with MAMP, the LESS compile of Twitter Bootstrap has a delay of 2 or 3 seconds.  It's fine for other contexts, but with WP's theme customizer, the page refresh happens faster than the LESS compile does.  All of that is beside the point though, the original question doesn't have the needed detail to make either of us clearly right, it's just a matter of opinion so not much point in debating it.

Comment: Seems like no pre-processor would be suitable for that workflow regardless of language. If the changes to the source document are being 'submitted' and then need to be available microseconds later on page reload then you're going to have a bad time. I'd suggest something that was able to pause page loading (server response) until the new css file had been generated. If LESS editing via a web gui is the problem, then I'd imagine that lots of people have that same problem? (and thats not the same as _this_ question which is similar, but different).

Answer (score 2):

You can use less (http://lesscss.org/). The main difference between sass and less, is that less can run on the client side.

Comment: run == compile at runtime (everytime) == much slower. Although I can see why it would be an advantage during development (though there are sass workflows that auto complile when changes are made).

Answer (score 2):

I just found LESSPHP that does what is says: gives you LESS for PHP.
http://leafo.net/lessphp/

Comment: yeah but LESS is a poor man's SCSS and isn't compatible with compass

Answer (score 1):

I just got SASS to work on my Ubuntu dev machine thanks to kissmyface.  I started with ZERO understanding of how SASS works and ABSOLUTELY no Ruby experience.  Here's the step by step:

Install ruby and SASS (assumes you're root):

```
> apt-get install ruby
> apt-get install rubygems
> gem install sass
> gem install listen
```

I had to install the listen gem to fix a bug where listening was broken.  Gems are like teh Ruby equivalent of apt packages, or Apache modules, or whatever.

SASS runs as a service and compiles .sass and .scss files into .css files.  Here is how to start the sass service, tell it to watch input.scss, and compile it to output.css when a change is detected:

```
> sass --watch input.scss:output.css
```

You can also have SASS watch a directory and probably do other fun stuff, docs are here: http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html

Much gratitude to kissmyface :)  Also, kissmyface is right on about running an Linux VM on Windows - I use VmWare to run an Ubuntu VM to get the awesome benefit of NetBeans IDE with PHP debugging :)

Regarding deploying it on shared hosting, good luck with that :/  I will probably just use SASS during development - when the site is done, I'll simply deploy the compiled CSS file(s).

Comment: On a related note: Foundation responsive CSS framework apparently integrates with SASS, and has similar installation instructions here: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/compass.php

Answer (score 0):

The best parser I've seen for PHP so far is this one.

http://code.google.com/p/phamlp/

It look slike it hasn't been touched in nearly 2 years, but it's still the best one I've seed so far.